# Multi Language iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, multilingual

How can I make a string for multi languages?

I want this rule for more languages.

```
localNotification.alertBody = "You have received \(Int(msg)) new messages"
```

I want this:

U_Have = "You have receive"; (English)

U_Have = "U heeft"; (Dutch)

New_msg = "new messages"; (English)

New_msg = "nieuwe berichten"; (Dutch)

I think it will looks lik this:

```
localNotification.alertBody = "U_Have \(Int(msg)) New_msg"
```

But how can I make this possible with Swift for iOS?

Comment: By using localization, not via code, have you looked into localization of iOS apps using Xcode? If the push messages come from a server you have to localize there probably.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do -- translating words, not whole phrases -- goes badly wrong in some languages.

There is a lot of literature on locatization and best practices. Go, have a read, maybe start [here](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/).

Answer (score 1):

Try sth like this:

```
func getSystemLanguage() -> String{
        var Language: String = "en"

        if let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String? {
            Language = preferredLanguage
            if(Language.rangeOfString("en") == nil && Language.rangeOfString("da") == nil){
                Language = "en";
            }

            if Language.rangeOfString("en") != nil {
                Language = "en";
            }

            if(Language.rangeOfString("da") != nil){
                Language = "da"
            }
        }
        return Language
    }
```

And then:

```
if(getSystemLanguage == "da"){
U_Have = "U heeft"; (Dutch)
} else {
U_Have = "You have receive"; (English)
}
```

I highly recommend you to put all strings in one file and do sth like this because if u don't you'll have much work if u add a new language:

```
class LocalizedStrings {
class func getVariable(Variable: String) -> String{

            var Key: String = "Key"
            switch (Variable) {
            case "Test":
                if(Logic.getSystemLanguage() == "da"){
                   Key = "Dutch"
                    return Key
                } else {
                    Key = "English"
                    return Key
                }
        default:
        return "NotFound"
            }
          }
       }
```

And then:

```
LocalizedString.getVariable("Test")
```

If you just want to localize strings you set in the storyboard it is much easier:

Comment: Why exactly are you promoting not using `NSLocalizedString()` and the accomanying tools Apple ships? Not using existing ways that serve well and cooking up custom code is seldomly a good idea. Also, keep in mind to not localize parts of phrases but whole phrases, especially with interpolation involved. Otherwise, it is bound to go horribly wrong.

Comment: The truth is I used this logic for my alerts without thinking about NSLocalizedStrings and I lieked it. I didn't have any trouble with this but my projects weren't really big. I think you are that NSLocalizedStrings are probably the better solution but I haven't tryed them yet. I'll try them next time.